# Apple Sign In - How to let users to invite others?

Tags: swift, apple-sign-in

I am developing a Swift based iOS app, which requires Apple Sign In. At some point, users may prefer to share some app-specific information with their friends or families. So they need to invite others via the app.

Due to regulations of Apple, I may not reach the user email addresses if they don't share this information. The app uses Firebase on the backend, however what I can get is ***user name***, ***privaterelay mail address***, and ***userID***.

What I want is when a user enters an email address of her friend, I can match the data with other's. I may alternatively use some system generated code, but this will also require some additional apps such as Messages or Mail.

Under this circumstances, do you have any clue, how I let users to invite others, without a painful method?

Thank you in advance.